# FacesMessage added from a ViewScoped bean not rendered

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I have a ViewScoped bean with the following method:

```
public Item getItem()  
{
     try {
          itemID = Integer.parseInt(
             FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                         .getRequestParameterMap().get("itemID"));  
     } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
          FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                       FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Item lookup error", null));
          return null;  
     }  
     return itemsDAO.findByID(itemID);
}
```

The method takes the ViewID param and look up the Object using the `itemsDAO`. I wanted to display a FacesMessage if the itemID is not integer by catching the `NumberFormatException` and adding the message in there. This however does not work. The `FacesMessage` in the above code snippet does not render inside the following view tag `h:messages globalOnly="true" infoClass="info" errorClass="error"`

I'm suspecting that the `FacesContext` is not available by the time the method is called, but I have no idea how to go about handling this exception.

Update 1:

About the suggestion to use viewParam to make use of built-in conversion and validation. I don't know how this is going to work in this case. The itemID is being passed from an "index" view where all items are listed as shown below. Each item title is a link to the viewItem page with the itemID being passed through URL. How can I use the viewParam to pass the itemID to the viewItem view in this case given that the index view has many items?

index.xhtml

```
<code>
 <ui:repeat var="item" value="#{ItemViewBean.items}">
       <div id="item">
        <h:link value="#{item.title}" outcome="viewItem">
        <f:param name="itemID" value="#{item.id}"></f:param>
        </h:link>
        <p><h:outputText value="#{item.description}"></h:outputText> <br />
        Address: <h:outputText value="#{item.address}"></h:outputText></p>
        <span class="itemFooter">
        Submitted By: <h:outputText value="#{item.user.username}"></h:outputText> On
        <h:outputText value="#{item.postDate}"></h:outputText>
        </span>
       <hr />
       </div>
       </ui:repeat>
</code>
```

Update 2:
I came up with one workaround for this issue. If an exception occurs, I put the error FacesMessage in the Flash object and redirect to some error page. I still don't understand why   the FacesMessage can't be simply added to the FacesContext and displayed on the view.

Comment: How do you know that this exactly does not work? Are you sure the method addMessage is being called? Are you getting an error? Are you doing an AJAX request (if you are, you have to update the h:messages)?

Comment: @elias I know it does not work because the h:messages tag is empty if I intentionally cause the exception by setting itemID to a string when it expects an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you're traversing `ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()`, you seem to be intercepting on a GET request. Given that it takes place in a getter method ([bad!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062)), it seems to be executed only when the component which references the `item` property is to be rendered.

So, assuming that the above assumptions are true, then this problem will manifest when the `<h:messages>` component is declared in the view *before* the component which references the `item` property. It's then namely too late to add a new message to the faces context. The `<h:messages>` is at that point namely *already* rendered.

I can at least not think of other reasonable causes matching this specific problem symptoms. There are basically 2 solutions to the problem:

1. Move the `<h:messages>` to *after* the component which references the `item` property, so that it's rendered *after* the faces message is been added.
2. Perform the business job during pre render view event by `<f:event>`, preferably in combination with `<f:viewParam>` to set the request parameter as a bean property. You can even use alone a `<f:viewParam>` in combination with a converter given that the sole job of your bad getter approach is converting the value.

Needless to say that option 2 is preferred given that you're currently basically abusing/workarounding some basic JSF concepts. Among others that business logic doesn't belong in getters.

E.g.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="itemID" name="itemID" value="#{bean.item}"
        required="true" requiredMessage="Invalid page access. Please use a link from within the system."
        converter="itemConverter" converterMessage="Unknown item ID."
    />
</f:metadata>
<h:message for="itemID" />
```

With

```
private Item item; // +getter +setter
```

The `itemConverter` is just a `Converter` implementation wherein the request parameter is converted to an `Item` instance in `getAsObject()` method.

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for/6377957#6377957)
- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. Option 1 would not work because I require the message to be displayed at the top of the page, it just can't be below the component in my design. For option 2, please see my Update 1 post edit to see how this is a problem for me

Comment: As per your update 1: put the metadata/viewparam in the page associated with outcome `viewItem`. See also the "See also" links for more detailed examples. As per your update 2: flash works because the message is added *before* the `<h:messages>` is rendered. Not using flash fails because the message is added *after* the `<h:messages>` is rendered. Exactly as I tried to explain in my answer.

Comment: Thank you BalusC for clearing this up. I had a huge misconception of the viewParam tag. This worked for me. Thank you for your support and for all your awesome answers on the JSF tag.